# How i can change language textbox in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am new with WPF.

I'm trying to change the language within the text box when writing inside,
In a window form  i was using this code.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo TypeOfLanguage = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage);
```

The problem I do not know how I will be able to change the language 
Because the code does not work in WPF.

Please help me How i can change the input language ?

Comment: This is controlled from keyboard and Windows OS, why to put the functionality inside your program. A shift+Alt will normaly do the job

Comment: Just a guess...  did you try changing the UI culture?

Comment: @apomene Because I want to put on a text box a default language regardless of the language system

Comment: @GayotFow yes i want this, but i do not how in wpf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to acomplish that you have to use  [InputLanguageManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputlanguagemanager.aspx) Class

```
this.Dispatcher.Thread.CurrentCulture.Name.ToString();
InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(myTextBox, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr"));
tb2.Text = "Available Input Languages:";
lb1.ItemsSource = InputLanguageManager.Current.AvailableInputLanguages;
tb3.Text = "Input Language of myTextBox is " + InputLanguageManager.GetInputLanguage(myTextBox).ToString();
tb4.Text = "CurrentCulture is Set to " + this.Dispatcher.Thread.CurrentCulture.Name.ToString();
```

Note: Code pasted form above link...

Comment: Thank's for your help , this Code it's working ,thank's for everyone who replied