# C# use different keyboard layout in different text boxes automatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to have three textboxes for user input, but for each textbox I would like a different keyboard layout to be used while entering text (without the need to manually change the kayboard layout).

In textxbox 1 I would like my normal (swedish) keyboard layout to be used while I write. In the second I would like to have Japanese Hiragana layout. And in the third I would like too have Japanese Katakana layout.

Is it possible to do?

As it is now I must manually change the keyboard layout with Windowskey+Space (this cycles through all keyboard layouts).

Comment: I found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080477/how-i-can-change-language-textbox-in-wpf I think the answer there should help, but I haven't tested it myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you:

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get index of current Input Language
    int currentLang = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage);
    // Calculate next Input Language
    InputLanguage nextLang = ++currentLang == InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.Count ? InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages[0] : InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages[currentLang];
    // Change current Language to the calculated:
    ChangeInputLanguage(nextLang);
}

public void ChangeInputLanguage(InputLanguage InputLang)
{
    // Check is this Language really installed. Raise exception to warn if it is not:
    if (InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(InputLang) == -1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    // InputLAnguage changes here:
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLang;
}
```

Here is the reference link - [Change Input Language programmatically?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/snippets/2008/12/31/how-to-change-input-language-programmatically/)