# How to set the DateFormat (Language) in a textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, globalization

I have a WPF application where I am dynamic creating the XAML which includes a textbox to display the current DATE and I want to show it in FRENCH (because it includes the day of the week).

In the XAML itself this is easy:

```
<TextBox Name="OrderDateText"
    Text="{Binding Path=OrderDate, StringFormat=dddd: dd-MM-yyyy}"
    xml:lang="fr-CA"
```

However when done in CODE I cannot seem to figure out how to set the language:

```
TextBox txtboxOrderdDate = new TextBox();
txtboxOrderdDate.Language = ???????????????????
{
   StringFormat = "dddd: dd-MM-yyyy"
};
txtboxOrderdDate.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080477/how-i-can-change-language-textbox-in-wpf), have you tried to search for an answer before posting the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `XMLLanguage` from `System.Windows.Markup` namespace:

```
txtboxOrderdDate.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("fr-CA");
```

Note that based on your Xaml, you should set `StringFormat` in your `Binding`, not in `Language`.

```
txtboxOrderdDate.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding()
{
    StringFormat = "some format here",
    OtherProps = ...
});
```